# Anuncio admob hace que mi app se detenga

Tags: java, android, admob

Estoy intentando que cuando sea "x" minuto (se indica en la condición del `if` que contiene el hilo de ejecución) salte un anuncio intersticial automáticamente (para esto he creado un hilo). El problema viene cuando el anuncio ha de saltar: sale la pantalla en negro como si fuera a cargarse y la aplicación deja de funcionar.

Cuando pruebo el código del anuncio intersticial normal en la función principal si funciona bien, pero en el hilo secundario no lo consigo hacer funcionar.

Os dejo mi código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AdView mAdView;
    InterstitialAd nAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.admob_app_id));
        MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.banner_id));
        MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.interstitial_id));

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        nAdView = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);            
        nAdView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_id));
        AdRequest adRequest2 = new 
        AdRequest.Builder().build();
        nAdView.loadAd(adRequest2);                
        nAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            displayInterstitial();
            }
        });

        WebView view = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        view.loadUrl("www.youtube.com");

        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public boolean shouldOverriceUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                return false;
            }
        });

        MiHilo miHilo = new MiHilo();
        miHilo.start();
    }

    public void displayInterstitial(){
        if(nAdView.isLoaded()){
            nAdView.show();

            nAdView = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);                    
            nAdView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_id));
            AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            nAdView.loadAd(adRequest2);
        }
    }

    private class MiHilo extends Thread {
        InterstitialAd nAdView;

        @Override
        public void run(){
            int minuto, segundo;
            Date d;

            while(true){
                d=new Date();
                minuto=d.getMinutes();
                segundo=d.getSeconds();
                if(minuto==38 && segundo==0){
                    displayIntersticial();
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Saludos y gracias por la ayuda de antemano

El error que me da es este:

```
2019-08-30 11:45:19.601 11225-11296/com.example.abcd E/chromium: [ERROR:devtools_http_handler.cc(292)] Cannot start http server for devtools. Stop devtools.

2019-08-30 11:45:19.758 11225-11225/com.example.abcd E/Ads: Google Mobile Ads SDK initialization functionality unavailable for this session. Ad requests can be made at any time.

2019-08-30 11:47:00.076 11225-11330/com.example.abcd E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6

Process: com.example.abcd, PID: 11225

java.lang.IllegalStateException: setImmersiveMode must be called on the main UI thread.

at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkMainThread(Unknown Source:46)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcqc.setImmersiveMode(Unknown Source:81)

at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzabb.zza(Unknown Source:57)

at com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.loadAd(Unknown Source:9)

at com.example.abcd.MainActivity.displayInterstitial(MainActivity.java:53)

at com.example.abcd.MainActivity$MiHilo.run(MainActivity.java:79)
```

Dejo la función tal que así?

```
public void displayInterstitial(){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (nAdView.isLoaded()) {
                    nAdView.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Puedes añadir el stackerror que te aparece por logcat?

Comment: Si claro, he añadido el mensaje de error en el mensaje principal @solamente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Añade el interstitial al thread principa, añade este código a la función displayInterstitial.

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            if (nAdView.isLoaded()) {
              nAdView.show();
         }
        }
    });
```

Comment: La he editado así pero me saltan dos errores nuevos (los pongo en el mensaje principal) @solamente

Comment: Prueba de quitarle el MainActivity a ver si con el runOnUiThread a secas ya te deja lanzarlo

Comment: Ahora si que me deja lanzarla, entonces desde el if(minuto==38 && segundo==0) llamo a la función displayIntersticial()? @solamente

Comment: Correcto y no debería darte el pete que comentaste en el primer post.

Comment: Efectivamente, ahora funciona perfectamente muchas gracias. Una pregunta, si ahora quisiera llamar por segunda vez la función displayIntersticial() que debería cambiar? Si la llamo tal cual está ahora solo aparece el anuncio la primera vez. @solamente

Comment: @Gorpe, si esta respuesta te ha resuelto el problema, sugiero que la marques como aceptada. Eso ayudará a futuros navegantes a identificar rápidamente que la respuesta ha sido efectiva para ti. Un saludo.

Comment: Vale, he hecho unos cambios y ya permite llamar al anuncio tantas veces como queramos. Todo bien ahora si